# How can i clear or empty an input box in adf

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

i want to clear/empty an input box on click of a button.i am using:

```
propInp.setValue("");
```

where propInp is the binding name of inputbox.

my input box is as:

```
<af:inputText label="UPC :" id="it2"
                                  binding="#{w9manageBean.propInp}"
                                  autoSubmit="true"
                                  showRequired="true"
                                  disabled="true" partialTriggers="::s1:cb1"
                                  required="true"/>
```

But this is not working...any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the value attribute for that inputText and set that backing bean property to an empty string.

`<af:inputText label="UPC :" id="it2"

    binding="#{w9manageBean.propInp}"

    autoSubmit="true"

    showRequired="true"

    disabled="true" partialTriggers="::s1:cb1"

    required="true"

    value="#{w9manageBean.myInput}"/>`

Add variable myInput to the managed bean and setter and getter for it. Then you can programaticaly set any value you want for that variable and it will be displayed in UI.

Comment: i got my mistake i am using inputbox inside a subform which is causing this mistake.Its working fine after removing subform.

why is subform generating such issue?any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I can google and get  a few different answers.
Maybe this post will help?
http://biemond.blogspot.com/2009/02/reset-clear-adf-page.html